# In Ibatis, how does one write a nested Iterate tag to loop through a two-dimensional array?

Tags: ibatis, loops

I was troubleshooting the following code and was unable to find an answer, so I figured I would document my solution.

The problem was:

```
<iterate property="twoDimArray" prepend="and (" close=")" conjunction="or">
    <iterate property="twoDimArray[]" open="(" close=")" conjunction="and">  
        $twoDimArray[][].columnName$ = #twoDimArray[][].value#  
    </iterate>  
</iterate>
```

Resulted in an error:
**There is no READABLE property named 'columnName' ...**

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to reference the second array as a property of the first:
`$twoDimArray[]`**.**`[].columnName$ = #twoDimArray[]`**.**`[].value#`